# for science project I'm direct messaging twitter with twitter4j lib and android 2.1 but app immediately crashes

Tags: android, twitter

I'm a complete beginner in java but I need to make this application to send commands over twitter.  I'm using the twitter4J library and android 2.1.  I finally have my code with no errors but when the app starts in the emulator, it immediately crashes.  Has anyone done this before?

CODE(main file):

```
package edu.shs.SHSSRP;

import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import edu.shs.SHSSRP.TwitterTest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SHSSRP extends Activity {
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */  
WebView webview;
Button Forward;
Button Backward;
Button Left;
Button Right;
TwitterTest TwitTest;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
 Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance("SHSSRP","123ABC1234");
 try {
    Status status = twitter.updateStatus("HELLO WORLD!");
} catch (TwitterException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
/*        Forward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Forward);
    Backward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Backward);
    Left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Left);
    Right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Right);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    TwitTest.runTest();
 */       
   }
}
```

CODE(function)

```
package edu.shs.SHSSRP;

import twitter4j.DirectMessage;
import twitter4j.ResponseList;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import android.app.Activity;
import twitter4j.*;

public class TwitterTest extends Activity 
{
 public void runTest() 
 {
       // The factory instance is re-usable and thread safe. 
       Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance("SenderID","SenderPass");
       try {
        twitter.sendDirectMessage("ReceiverID", "HelloWorld");
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

CODE(manifest)
simply add the uses permission for interet

CODE(layout)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Forward"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/webview"
        android:text="@string/Forward" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/Forward" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"           
        android:text="@string/Left" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/Forward"
        android:text="@string/Right" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Backward"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/Right"
        android:text="@string/Backward" />
```

thank you in advance,

Matt

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to utilize `LogCat` class, you can use statements to debug to the console, like `Log.v("MyActivity", "Clicking the button now");` and it will report to console. It helps to show what exactly is going on and what is causing problems.

Comment: Can you post the exception printed out in LogCat?

Answer (score 1):

In your AndroidManifest.xml file you need to specify that your application will connect to the internet.

Paste this just above the `<application>` node:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: thanks, jeremynealbrown for answering but I'd already done that and did have it in my post but it was only 1 line, i didn't copy in the whole manifest so it's my fault but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the other folk have indicated, posting the stack trace would be a big help.

That being said, you might also consider switching to [JTwitter](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php). I know from [first-hand](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/16-JAR/) [experience](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/TwitterWidget/) that it works on Android, though I tend to remove the duplicate `org.json` classes that JTwitter has in its published JAR.